# CSS animation scale transform starts blurry in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations, rendering, css-transforms

<sup>*(**Note**: This was asked [exactly] **1½ years** ago and had [exactly] zero activity... I'm apparently having the same issue so hopefully OP [@Jaffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11282707/jaffa?tab=topactivity) won't mind me piggybacking in it, and slapping a bounty on it to [hopefully] generate some interest!*)</sup>

<sup>*The OP's original question is **below**, and my added issue & examples is **below that**.*</sup>

---

<sub>***[Original Question:]***</sub>
I am trying to animate a zoom out effect on an SVG. I have gotten it working, *but* the first frame, which is scaled to 30, is blurry/pixelated  in Firefox.

**Firefox**: [image]
**Chrome**: [image]

I do not see the same issue in Chrome or Edge. The initial frame is crisp as I would expect being an SVG.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 50px 50px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.img_zoom {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 2em auto 2em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.zoom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: zoom 5s ease-in-out 4s 1 normal forwards;
  transform: translate(3400px, -3600px) scale(30);
}
@keyframes zoom {
  to {
    margin-left: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.7);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img_zoom">
      <div class="zoom"><img src="https://flexion.tech/images/box-con.svg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code pen is here for review:

https://codepen.io/jaffa80/pen/KKpxgeQ

Any ideas how I can fix the blurry issue in Firefox?

Another problem i am having is if I remove margin-left:0 from the @keyframe to, things stop working. Any pointers on this would be appreciated also.

---

### EDIT:

I have a rounded div container containing several elements to position text within the circle.  I need the circle to "grow" when the user gets to it, so I figured I'd use `transform:scale()` with a transition or animation.

However, **only in Firefox**, the text is blurry until the transition (or animation) is complete.  Oddly, the border of the circle remains perfectly sharp (I think?).

[image]

Thinking maybe it needed a moment to pre-render, I've tried delaying with `setTimeout` alone, as well as combining with events (`open` & `DOMContentLoaded`) and with `requestAnimationFrame`. I also tried using css `animation` instead of `transition`.

Nothing seems to make a difference in Firefox, yet Chrome and Edge seem fine.  Is there a **prefix** that I don't know about, or is this maybe a rendering **bug** in Firefox?

My MCSE is the **snippet below**:

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
  circ.classList.remove('shrunk');
},500);
```

```css
body{ font-family:'fira code'; font-size:20px; }
#circ{ position:relative; border:3px solid blue; border-radius:50%; text-align:center; white-space: nowrap; transition:transform 1000ms; }
#circ span{ position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); }
.shrunk{ transform:scale(0.1); }
```

```html
<div class='shrunk' id='circ' style='width:336px; height:336px;'>
  <span>Lorem<br>Ipsum is simply<br>dummy text of the<br>printing and typesetting<br>industry. Lorem Ipsum has<br>been the industry's<br>standard dummy text ever<br>since the 1500s, when an<br>unknown printer took a<br>galley of type and<br>scrambled it to make<br>a type specimen<br>book.</span>
</div>
```

*Any suggestions or workarounds?*

Answer (score 6):

I can only guess why this happens. Firefox is taking a snapshot before starting the animation / transition (by adding the class to the tag) and then when the transition ends.  Maybe Firefox is taking more than two snapshots. But as you can see in the snippet below, the **animation** label is still blurred and waiting for when the animation is finished; the blur then disappears immediately. I think Firefox does this optimization for better performance.

The CSS property `will-change` also does not solve this problem if reset to *initial* .

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  circ.classList.add('shrunk');
}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  font-family: 'fira code';
  gap: 2rem;
}

.circles,
.titles {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

h4 {
  width: 105px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#circ,
#circ2,
#circ3,
#circ4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}

#circ {
  transition: transform 1000ms;
  transform: scale(0.1);
}

#circ2 {
  animation: forwardAnim 5s linear forwards;
}

#circ3 {
  animation: forwardAnim 5s linear forwards;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#circ4 {
  animation: forwardAnim 5s linear forwards;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#circ span,
#circ2 span,
#circ3 span,
#circ4 span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#circ.shrunk {
  transform: scale(1);
}

@keyframes forwardAnim {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  45% {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div id="circ">
    <span>This is my text!</span>
  </div>
  <div id="circ2">
    <span>This is my text!</span>
  </div>

  <div id="circ3">
    <span>This is my text!</span>
  </div>
  <div id="circ4">
    <span>This is my text!</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="titles">
  <h4>Add class with transition</h4>
  <h4>Animation</h4>
  <h4>Animation with backface-visibility: hidden</h4>
  <h4>Animation with transform-style: preserve-3d</h4>
</div>
```

To avoid this you could use `backface-visibility: hidden;`as [@nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69294282/8112776) mentions above, or `transform-style: preserve-3d;`* for a smoother transition.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  circ.classList.remove('shrunk');
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  circ2.classList.remove('shrunk');
}, 500);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  font-family: 'fira code';
  gap: 2rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.circles,
.titles {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

h4 {
  width: 255px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#circ,
#circ2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: transform 1000ms;
}

#circ {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#circ2 {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#circ span,
#circ2 span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.shrunk {
  transform: scale(0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="shrunk" id="circ">
    <span>Lorem<br />Ipsum is simply<br />dummy text of the<br />printing and
          typesetting<br />industry. Lorem Ipsum has<br />been the industry's<br />standard
          dummy text ever<br />since the 1500s, when an<br />unknown printer
          took a<br />galley of type and<br />scrambled it to make<br />a type
          specimen<br />book.</span
        >
      </div>
      <div class="shrunk" id="circ2">
        <span
          >Lorem<br />Ipsum is simply<br />dummy text of the<br />printing and
          typesetting<br />industry. Lorem Ipsum has<br />been the industry's<br />standard
          dummy text ever<br />since the 1500s, when an<br />unknown printer
          took a<br />galley of type and<br />scrambled it to make<br />a type
          specimen<br />book.</span
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="titles">
      <h4>backface-visibility: hidden;</h4>
      <h4>transform-style: preserve-3d;</h4>
    </div>
```

Another way to avoid blurred content inside the circle is to remove `position: absolute` if it's not critical, and instead align content with `display: flex` on the parent element.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  circ.classList.remove('shrunk');
}, 500);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'fira code';
  font-size: 20px;
}

#circ {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: transform 1000ms;
}

.shrunk {
  transform: scale(0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="shrunk" id="circ" style="width: 336px; height: 336px">
  <span>Lorem<br />Ipsum is simply<br />dummy text of the<br />printing and
        typesetting<br />industry. Lorem Ipsum has<br />been the industry's<br />standard
        dummy text ever<br />since the 1500s, when an<br />unknown printer took
        a<br />galley of type and<br />scrambled it to make<br />a type
        specimen<br />book.</span
      >
    </div>
```

Comment: It was difficult to decide which answer should be awarded the bounty... both contained the solution that worked for me (`backface-visibility: hidden`) and both had good info, in different forms. Sadly I [can't split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users) the points between the two. Thus, I admit that the tie breaker was the fact that the bounty rep have 500% more impact on one user's overall reputation (and I remember getting through that first 2k being a real pain in the behind!). Thanks to both answers. 

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue a few years back, although I think I had it on chrome and not Firefox. But this seems to solve the issue in Firefox too.

Add `backface-visibility: hidden` to your transforming component. This will make it so that only the front face of the element is animated, instead of both the front and the back faces.

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
  circ.classList.remove('shrunk');
},500);
```

```css
body{ font-family:'fira code'; font-size:20px; }
#circ{ position:relative; border:3px solid blue; border-radius:50%; text-align:center; white-space: nowrap; transition:transform 1000ms; backface-visibility: hidden; }
#circ span{ position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); }
.shrunk{ transform:scale(0.1); }
```

```html
<div class='shrunk' id='circ' style='width:336px; height:336px;'>
  <span>Lorem<br>Ipsum is simply<br>dummy text of the<br>printing and typesetting<br>industry. Lorem Ipsum has<br>been the industry's<br>standard dummy text ever<br>since the 1500s, when an<br>unknown printer took a<br>galley of type and<br>scrambled it to make<br>a type specimen<br>book.</span>
</div>
```

As to why it works, I really have no idea. But do try it and let me know it if works for you.